# How to add listings using event tracking in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to add listings like this screenshot which is photoshopped:

[image: Analytics listing]

The real result that I didn't want this, one list is totally stacked.

[image]

My script when someone uses input as number and click button to send data:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'User Behavior', 'Input & Button', 'Individual count', variable_input_number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Event value is a metric, so the second example is actually the expected result - metrics are always added up. The only way to get the breakdown would be if you have at least one dimension (label presumably in your case, or adding a custom dimension and setting it as secondary dimension in your report) that is different per event. If you want to record each individual number as it is submitted you should probably use the number as event label and group by event category, but you cannot break down events by individual values.

Comment: I understand, so no problem... would you mind to make an example? thanks